# Troubles installing ubuntu from a DVD

Tags: boot, system-installation

I am trying install ubuntu on Toshiba Satellite and I am having some difficulties. This is my first time installing a linux operating system. I have installed it onto a DVD and have created a 24 gb partion for it on my C: drive. When I put the disk in and do a restart it boots up into the black menu where I have a few options one of them being try linux and another being install linux. I select the install linux. It then goes to the purple screen that says ubuntu with the loading dots under it. That is as far as it gets. I've let it sit for 30 minutes and it never gets past that step.

Comment: what version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Im using 16.04.1 LTS

Comment: your DVD might be corrupt/partially written/scratched/etc. Try burning another DVD, or write the iso image to a USB flash drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the purple splash screen, press the up key on your keyboard, it will show at which step it's getting stuck.

Also try booting the LiveCD with the "acpi=off", "noapic", "nolapic" and "nomodereset" boot parameters. All is explained here: https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/installation-guide/i386/ch05s04.html

Comment: It's hanging up at "pwconv: failed to change the mod of /etc/passwd- to 0600

Comment: It got passed that step now I think, but now its saying "Failed to start login service"

Comment: I have tried nomodereset I will try the others

Comment: still am getting the same errors with all of those

Comment: Do you have the possibility to try this DVD on another PC? No need to install,  just try to make it boot. Something else you could try is booting from USB: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick , I have had different results in the past by simply using a different media for the installation.

Answer (score 0):

i was trying hard to install ubuntu from USB as well as from DVD.
however, it was failing.
some error like error no 5 was coming

But when i tried the installation from DVD in a air conditioned room (~20 degree), it worked.

this may be useful for users in hot climate.